# I can't use Intent at Activity

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

when I click the marker on **Google Map**, I want it to enter another **Activity**, but when I got the result from **javascript**, it can't do Intent

```
WebSettings webSetting = webView.getSettings();
webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
webSetting.setSupportZoom(true);
webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterfaceTest(this), "Android");
```

and my `JavaScriptInterfaceTest()`:

```
public class JavaScriptInterfaceTest {
  Context mContext;

  /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
  JavaScriptInterfaceTest(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
  }

  /** Show a toast from the web page */
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void responseResult(String result){
    Log.e("JsCallBack","DRINK");
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
  }

  @JavascriptInterface
  private void startActivity(Intent mainIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
drinkMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: {lat: 25.079734,lng: 121.569519},
                   map: map,
                   });
drinkMarker.addListener('click',function(){
                        Android.responseResult("drink");
                        });
```

Comment: try using startActivityForResult

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: like startActivityForResult(mainIntent,0); ?

Comment: i got no error when i run the app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the Current context instead of MainActivity

```
public class JavaScriptInterfaceTest {
  Context mContext;

  /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
  JavaScriptInterfaceTest(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
  }

  /** Show a toast from the web page */
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void responseResult(String result){
    Log.e("JsCallBack","DRINK");
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(mContext, Test.class);
     mContext.startActivity(mainIntent);
  }

  @JavascriptInterface
  private void startActivity(Intent mainIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```